# How to implement "or" in request?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have this query:

```
var TheQuery = db.Conventions.Where(p => 
    p.Participants.Select(q => q.intituleParticipant).Contains(s));
```

and I need to add other conditions...

How is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `||` operator, same as you would use in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same way you'd add another condition in regular C#, by using the `||` (OR) operator.

```
var TheQuery = db.Conventions.Where(p =>
       p.Participants.Select(q => q.intituleParticipant).Contains(s) ||
       othercondition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your query  ||

or -->  ||

```
var TheQuery = db.Conventions.Where(p => p.Participants.Select(q => q.intituleParticipant).Contains(s) || other conditions);
```